# how to alert if the cuit is valid or not?

Tags: javascript, function, validation

I have an input with the id `cuit` and I need to validate this input in Argentina. I found this code but now I want to run an alert or something to know if `cuit` is valid or not.

how can I do this?

```
function validaCuit(sCUIT) {
    var aMult = '5432765432';
    var aMult = aMult.split('');

    if (sCUIT && sCUIT.length == 11) {
        aCUIT = sCUIT.split('');
        var iResult = 0;
        for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
            iResult += aCUIT[i] * aMult[i];
        }
        iResult = (iResult % 11);
        iResult = 11 - iResult;

        if (iResult == 11) iResult = 0;
        if (iResult == 10) iResult = 9;

        if (iResult == aCUIT[10]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Uhm, `alert( validaCuit(sCUIT) )`;` would alert true or false, assuming the function works

Comment: Please keep in mind [you shouldn't really use `alert()` in JavaScript for error checking, or at all if you are even slightly worried about UX](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/106039)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont like the true/false output the ternary (?) operator is your friend:

```
alert( validaCuit( "1234" ) ? "Valid Input!" : "Wrong input!");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're function returns a value. You need to `alert` that value.

Also, FYI make sure that you properly declare all your variables inside your function otherwise, they become global.

```js
function validaCuit(sCUIT)
{
    var aMult = '5432765432';
    var aMult = aMult.split('');

    if (sCUIT && sCUIT.length == 11)
    {
        aCUIT = sCUIT.split('');
        var iResult = 0;
        for(i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            iResult += aCUIT[i] * aMult[i];
        }
        iResult = (iResult % 11);
        iResult = 11 - iResult;

        if (iResult == 11) iResult = 0;
        if (iResult == 10) iResult = 9;

        if (iResult == aCUIT[10])
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}

alert(validaCuit("12345678911"));
alert(validaCuit("1234567891"));
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function validaCuit(sCUIT)
{
    var aMult = '5432765432';
    var aMult = aMult.split('');

    if (sCUIT && sCUIT.length == 11)
    {
        aCUIT = sCUIT.split('');
        var iResult = 0;
        for(i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            iResult += aCUIT[i] * aMult[i];
        }
        iResult = (iResult % 11);
        iResult = 11 - iResult;

        if (iResult == 11) iResult = 0;
        if (iResult == 10) iResult = 9;

        if (iResult == aCUIT[10])
        {
            alert('CUIT is correct!');
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    alert('CUIT is incorrect!');
    return false;

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.